# Extract Drive Letter, java regex

Tags: java, regex, drive-letter

I cannot get this simple regex to work.  I need to check to see if the file path includes the drive letter, if it doesn't throw an exception.

```
if (!arcvalFileFormBean.getTxtFileReview().matches("^([A-Z]):")) {
    status = "MAPPING ERROR: Please submit a file from a mapped drive (i.e. K:\\).";
    request.setAttribute(FairValConstants.status, status);
    throw new InvalidFileMoveException(FairValConstants.MAKE_VALID_SELECTION);
}
```

When I test the code with this `W:\testFolder\testfile_v1234_12_23_2014_1245.pfd` it fails, when it should pass. When I test it without the drive letter, but the full path it fails.  There is something wrong with my regex. I have tried a few different regexs but nothing has worked.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is `matches("^([A-Z]):"))` since `String#matches` matched full input not just a part of it.

Try this instead to make it match full line:

```
if (!arcvalFileFormBean.getTxtFileReview().matches("((?i)(?s)[A-Z]):.*")) {
```

**PS:** `^` and `$` anchors are also not required in `String#matches` since that is implicit.

- `(?i)` => Ignore case
- `(?s)` => DOTALL (mase DOT match new lines as well)

Comment: `s` flag or maybe `d` flag is more appropriate here, since the file name is allowed to contain `\u0085`, `\u2028` and `\u2029`

Comment: You can write it as `(?is)[A-Z]:.*`

Comment: Thanks, Yes it can be written as that also, just wanted to be more verbose here for explanation purpose.

Answer (score 5):

matches() tests that the whole string matches the regex. So `A:` will match, but not `A:\blabla` (and `a:` neither).

The regex should be something like

```
^([A-Za-z]):.*$
```

Comment: `s` flag or maybe `d` flag is more appropriate here, since the file name is allowed to contain `\u0085`, `\u2028` and `\u2029`

Comment: I'm not a regex expert. What do you mean by "the s flag"? Where should it be added, and to do what?

Comment: By default `.` matches any character *except* `\n`, `\r`, `\u0085`, `\u2028`, `\u2029`. `s` flag makes `.` matches any character (no exception), while `d` flag makes `.` matches any character *except* only `\n`. You can use inline flag by `(?s)` or `(?d)`

Answer (score 0):

`matches` checks if entire string matches regex. What you are looking for is `find` from `Matcher` class.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(yourRegex);//you can save it as static field to reuse this regex

if (p.matcher(yourInput).find()){
    //do your job
}
```